# Need a query to conditionally display column

Tags: oracle

For example, if the front end can give a Date, then add Date='someDate' with necessary `AND` keyword, and also show up the `Date` column by `SELECT`. Otherwise that Date column do not show either in the condition string nor in the `SELECT`

It is like 
if the Date is not null
then

```
Select .... Date as Date01 from TableName where ....AND Date01='someDate';
```

if the Date is null
then

```
Select .... from TableName where ..;
```

How to achieve such goal? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return two separate select lists then you would need two queries to perform this.

You cannot hide a column in a `SELECT` list based on whether or not a date has been provided.

If you want to include the column and the condition, then you can use a `case` expression to provide a different value to the records that don't have the condition. Similar to this:

```
select 
   case when Date01='someDate' 
        then Date 
        else null end as Date01
from TableName
where yourFilters
  or Date01='someDate'
```

Comment: Thank you. But if we don't hide column in a SELECT but only hide a condition, is it doable?

Comment: @Dreamer see my edit, you can use a `case` to change the value of the column when the condition is met

Comment: Thanks again. What if when Date is not null, then we add Date column into the condition, like Date='someDate', if Date is null, then we don't add this column in the condition. Here assume we don't need to show the date column in the SELECT anymore.

Comment: But the column is still there, it is a part of the select list you can use the `case` to determine what the value of the column is.

Comment: Sorry I am really dumb, how can we conditionally add conditions after where clause? `where yourFilters or Date01='someDate'` does't seems right. It should be either `where yourFilters and Date01='someDate'` or `where yourFilters` but how to integrate the two in one, regardless of what we SELECT?

Comment: To add conditions, you will use either `AND` or `OR` to add filters to your query.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get what you mean.